# Issue in creation a GUI in core java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have to create this kind of GUI in core java using swing:

[image]

In this GUI :

> 1, 2, 3, 4... numbers are labels. These values are fixed.
>
> A, B, C, D... are editable textfield. User can enter any value here.

My Approach: Use table and put two textfeild in it. But not have any idea how to do this.

Is there any other easy approach to implement this part in core java?

Comment: any code so far yet ?

Comment: no progress yet. tried of putting textfeild in table. but not working

Comment: *"Is there any other **easy** approach to implement this part in core java?"* Hire someone. Get back to us if you decide to put the effort in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements shown, [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) grids may be a useful starting point.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41085019/230513
 */
public class GridTest {

    private static final int N = 12;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GridTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            panel.add(createPanel(i));
        }
        f.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel(int i) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 8, 8));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        panel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
        panel.add(new JLabel());
        panel.add(new JLabel());
        panel.add(new JTextField(String.valueOf(Character.valueOf((char) ('A' + i)))));
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GridTest()::display);
    }
}
```